# Fingerprint reader for LG Gram

Tags: fingerprint-reader

When will fingerprint reading be supported for LG Gram laptops? Currently it is not supported.

I looked up `lsusb` but the IDs listed there are not included in the fingerprint supported devices listed [here...](https://launchpad.net/%7Efingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui)

Comment: It's a question that only LG could answer. However as a side note, [the upcoming kernel will have support for some of LG Gram stuff](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LG-Gram-Laptop-Linux-Driver)  *(unfortunately no fingerprint reader yet)*. The support however wired up by an independent contributor, not LG. The kernel with this support will be released somewhere around new year *(but of course you always can test an unstable version if you want it)*.

Comment: Man, so many people are using LG Gram on linux ) Googling for almost half of the year.

Comment: I'm planning to buy one LG Gram soon... anyone here with a good experience installing Ubuntu 18?

Comment: @BetoAveiga I had issues with ubuntu 16/18. It took a long time to get up from suspend. The issue disappeared in 19.10. Sadly no fingerprint reader yet.

Comment: I'm loving it on Mint 19.3; it's an unbelievable laptop.

Comment: So, I got the LG GRAM a year ago or so, and I'm a happy Ubuntu user. I'm using it for web development. Drupal. All good. Installing Ubuntu was not easy, not for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately afaik the only effort  right now is in the libfprint repo which had an issue about it (but it got recently closed because a change of the support model)
[Libfprint issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/137)

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint reader works in Arch Gnome and KDE on my 2021 gram 17.  Just had to install fprintd.